# Mongo: Limit returned records to an incremental count on slice

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Im using mongoose within a node project, i have the following query:

```
var query = Model.aggregate(
        { $match: { id: id } },
        { $sort: { created: -1 } },
        {
            $project: {
                name: true,
                number: true,
                created: true,
                status: true,
                time: true,
                array_data: { $slice: ['$array_data', 5] }
            }
        }
    )
```

I thought slice would limit my entire records to 5 based on how many records were in the array_data filed, but it only limits the amount array_data elements that are returned.

What I am hoping to do is:

Lets say record 1 in my model has 10 elements in array_data
and record 2 in my model has 15 elements in array_data.

I want to be able to slice or use some other function so when I query my model with a 'limit' of 20 it returns the first collection with all of its 10 elements in array_data along with the second collection and its first 10 records in array_data that equals to  the 'limit' of 20.

Is this at all possible with Mongo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unwind` to deconstruct the documents, then limit it and group them again

```
var query = Model.aggregate(
        { $match: { id: id } },
        { $sort: { created: -1 } },
        { $unwind: '$array_data' },
        { $limit: 20 },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              name:'$name',
              number: '$number',
              created: '$created',
              status: '$status',
              time: '$time'
            },
            array_data: {
              $push: '$array_data'
            }
          }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                name: '$_id.name',
                number: '$_id.number',
                created: '$_id.created',
                status: '$_id.status',
                time: '$_id.time',
                array_data: 1,
                _id: 0
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: interesting approach ill have to try this one, thanks.

Comment: Any idea of the efficiency of this ?